# Rails strong parameters - multiple types (strings, array of strings and array of hashes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have the following params, that have different value type (1. string, 2. array of strings and 3. array of hashes) for the value key:

**Params**

```
project: {
  name: "Project 1",
  field_values_attributes: [
    {  
      field_component_id: 1, 
      value: "my_value"
    },
    {  
      field_component_id: 2, 
      value: ["my_value1", "my_value2"]
    },
    {  
      field_component_id: 3, 
      value: [
        {
          id: X,
          attributes: {
            uid: "my_uid",
            email: "my_email",
            full_name: "my_name"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Strong params:**

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, field_values_attributes: [ :field_component_id, :value, value: [ :id, attributes: [:uid, :email, :full_name]] ])
end
```

The strong params method permits the string and array of hashes, but not array of strings for the **value key**.

Any idea how to write the permit method to accept all three types?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `value: []` for achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have:

```rb
# for `value: "my_value"`
:value
 
# for `value: [{id: 1, ...}]`
value: [:id, attributes: [:uid, :email, :full_name]]

# for `value: ["my_value1", "my_value2"]`
value: []
```

But you can't have `value:` twice as a keyword argument for `permit`. You will have to do some manual shuffling:

```rb
project_params = params.require(:project).permit(:name).dup
project_params[:field_values_attributes] = params[:project][:field_values_attributes].map do |field|
  field.permit(
    :field_component_id,
    *case field[:value]
    in String
      [:value]
    in [String, *]
      [value: []]
    in [ActionController::Parameters, *]
      [value: [:id, attributes: [:uid, :email, :full_name]]]
    else
      []
    end
  )
end
project_params

#

>> project_params.permitted?
=> true
>> project_params.to_h 
=> {"name"=>"Project 1",
    "field_values_attributes"=>
     [{"field_component_id"=>1, "value"=>"my_value"},
      {"field_component_id"=>2, "value"=>["my_value1", "my_value2"]},
      {"field_component_id"=>3, "value"=>[{"id"=>4, "attributes"=>{"uid"=>"my_uid", "email"=>"my_email", "full_name"=>"my_name"}}]}]}
```